# Проблема Exception in thread „main“ java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, многопоточность, исключения

Возникает проблема при выводе элементарной программы:

```
class summenbildung {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int s = 0;
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        while (n>0) {
            s = s+n;
            n = n-1;
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Программа вроде простая, ошибок быть не должно, в связи с чем непонятно, по какой причине после компилирования консоль выдает Exception in thread „main“ java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 at summenbildung.main(summenbildung.java:4)

Может, проблема в настройках jdk на самом компьютере? Я в этом, к сожалению, плохо разбираюсь, поэтому любые советы приветствуются.

Answer (score 1):

String[ ] args в Java это массив строк которые хранят в себе аргументы положенные туда из командной строки при старте программы.

В вашей программе этот массив пустой, а вы пытаетесь обратиться к нулевому элементу, и которого не существует, на что и указывает компилятор ошибкой ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: А как можно исправить ошибку в данном случае? Что-то ввести перед программой? Я новичок в java.

Comment: @carnicorn нужно учиться такие ошибки гуглить, в противном случае программистом вы не станете

Comment: Я в целом вообще не понимаю зачем вы обращаетесь к этому массиву args? Какова ваша цель?

Comment: @Санаев я гуглил, но вылетали другие программы с другими переменными, что не так в моем случае, я честно без понятия. Пример этой программы был взят «из учебника», так что априори не должно быть ошибок.

Comment: @СергейБувака повторюсь: пример был взят «из учебника», в качестве вводного. Ни пояснений, ни комментариев к строкам к не было, так что не могу сказать точно, извините.

Answer (score 1):

Вы запускаете программу с  пустым массивом String[] args. Передавайте какой-нибудь параметр при запуске из командной строки: например, java summenbildung 5.
Также, чтобы не было ошибки при запуске без параметров, можно добавить условие "непустого" массива args, при котором будет выполняться ваш алгоритм.

```
class summenbildung {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int s = 0;
    if (args.length > 0) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        while (n>0) {
            s = s+n;
            n = n-1;
        }
    }       
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

}

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет, я попробую переписать код!